# How to click and drag select objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I don't have any experience with Illustrator and am trying to modify a file. There are a bunch of text objects (something like two dozen) and I simply want to select all of them without shift-clicking every single one. However, when I choose the selection tool and then click and drag to try to select the object, the background gets selected and starts moving with the mouse.

If I click outside of the layers and drag into them then I can select stuff, but it gets borders on the edges that I don't want to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into great detail about locking or hiding objects, or using the Layers Panel, the quickest method may be to choose `Select > Object > Text Objects` from the menu.

This will select *all* text objects. And this assumes your text is *live* text, not outlines.

You can then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click to remove pieces from the selection if needed.

There may be other methods which work equally well, but a sample of the artwork would need to be shown or at least explained in detail to provide simple solutions such as this.

Comment: Sometimes it is also a good idea to lock background objects, ot to have background objects on a special layer which could also be locked.